# After setting 6 digit password lock screen shows only 4 digit to enter the password using DevicePolicyManager Android

Tags: android, lockscreen, device-admin, device-policy-manager, android-device-owner

I am using lenovo tablet and in my application I have added below code. Also the application is set as Device Admin and Device Owner profile. After execution of this code the let suppose if the password is "123456". The password gets set and device screen get lock.
**Problem:** While unlocking It allowed me to enter only 4 digit not 6.

```
val devicePolicyManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as? DevicePolicyManager
devicePolicyManager.resetPasswordWithToken(
            componentName,
            password,
            token,
            0
        )
```

I also tried to set the password minimum length and password policy as numeric as below it didn't work.

```
public static void setPasswordLength(Context context, String password) {
      
            val devicePolicyManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as? DevicePolicyManager
            if (devicePolicyManager != null) {
                try {
                    devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(componentName, DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC);
                    devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(componentName, password.length());
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, exception);
                }
            }else{
                LogUtil.error(TAG, "DevicePolicyManager is null");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Note: The device is rooted device.